# How to save file which was sent to telebot from user Python?

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

I need to save a file which was sent to telegram bot.

```
import telebot
bot = "Here is my token"

@bot.message_handler(content_types='') #IDK what content type I need to use to receive every file
def addfile(message):
#Here I need to save file which was sent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would look something like this:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document', 'photo', 'audio', 'video', 'voice']) # list relevant content types
def addfile(message):
    file_name = message.document.file_name
    file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)
```

Comment: How I can find the file wich allready downloaded?Or change the path where it will save.

Comment: You can specify the path like this `with open('path/to/directory/' + file_name, 'wb')` otherwise it will just save to the directory where you run the code